# TurboTable select/unselect programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a TurboTable definition with checkbox selection like below:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="dataJSONArray" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [scrollable]="true"
  [(selection)]="dtSelectedRows" dataKey="OrderId">
  <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width: 3em">
      <col *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width': col.widthPx + 'px'}">
    </colgroup>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
      </th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-col>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td>
        <p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
      </td>
...
```

If i change dtSelectedRows array (selection), nothing happens (dtSelectedRows array changes, but checked columns does not change -stay checked-):

`this.dtSelectedRows.splice(indx, 1);`

But if i assign an array to dtSelectedRows array, changes take affect:

```
let dummySelectedRow = Object.assign([], this.dtSelectedRows);
dummySelectedRow.splice(indx, 1);
this.dtSelectedRows = dummySelectedRow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the selection mode proprty to `single` in this case the `dtSelectedRows` will be refrence to object instand of array of selected value.

> `<p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>` set
>   selection mode to `multiple` selection ,
>   you can solve this is to use p-tableRadioButton (radio button) if you want to support single selection mode

```
<p-table  [columns]="cols" [value]="data" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [scrollable]="true"
  [(selection)]="dtSelectedRows" >
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-col>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
       <td>
        <p-tableRadioButton [value]="rowData"></p-tableRadioButton>
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let col of cols">{{rowData[col.field]}}<td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

set selected item by method

```
  setSelectedItem(){
    this.dtSelectedRows = this.data[0];
  }
```

In case of you want to remove an item based on condition in multiple mode

```
  removeUnvalidItem(){
    if (this.dtSelectedRows) {
      this.dtSelectedRows = this.dtSelectedRows.filter(car => car.year > 2005) 
    }
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-select-mode)

Comment: I'm not sure if i could described my problem but this is not what i want. I do not want a single selection. I want to use multiselection, and select multi records. But in a button click, with a for operator, i'm iterating selected records and executing a service. If service returns ok response i will deselect that item (by removing from array), if service returns any error selection will be kept for that records. And i will process all records with this logic and successfull processed lines will be unselected and which lines take error will remain selected. I hope, i could described my case.

Comment: sorry I don't get what you want ,in summery in multiple dtSelectedRows  will be an array ,single will be an object  ,can you tell me which one work for you

Comment: I want multi selection with checkbox and there is not any problem in my code, it works well. Imagine that I have selected 5 records and then click a button (which calls a method for everyline) and if method returns true i will unselect those lines and if result is false those lines will remain selected.

Comment: to clear the selection just set dtSelectedRows = [] ; so kust check the false state

Comment: dtSelectedRows = [] ; clears all selection. As i mentioned i want to clear only some lines selection. If you look at main thread my second option is also unselect line by line, but via splice i can not delete one line. I do not want to remove all selections. I want to remove selections with a condition for every selected line. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: I am not clear about base on what do you want to remove the item but lts sa I want to remove some item there price is lest than 500 ,I can use filter because the dtSelectedRows  item is array :+1

Comment: I have update the demo and my answer hope I get your point :)

Comment: Sorry for late respoense, because of a travel i could not check your solution. Today i checked  your solution and it is mostly ok for me. Thank you so much.